# Ext 3.4 TextArea new line in string with setValue()

Tags: extjs, textarea, ext3

I have a basic ExtJs textarea with setValue. 
The value comes to ExtJs as a string from database.

The string is created in php.
Since it doesn't support HTML, `<br>` won't work.

It also seems to ignore `\r\n`  or `\n` or `\ \r\ \n` or `\ \n` - it will simply print it as text.

Is there any workarounds?

Comment: So, if I understand your situation, you have HTML strings that come from the db and you want them correctly rendered into the TextArea?

Comment: not html specifically - its a string created with a loop.
But i need each of the iterations from the loop to show up on a separate line for readability. Each iteration would have something like $string .= "param: old -> new" - with a line break/new line at the end of each of those.
These created strings are stored in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like ext  somehow escaped everything when  the datatype in store was string (i guess some ASCII values were set).

Adding string directly to setValue() works with \n.

As a workaround i used a custom palceholder %nl and used js replace to change them to \non setValue().